# Gnome session flashback - 2 parter question

Tags: gnome, panel-applets, gnome-flashback

1. Will Gnome session flashback be phased out once Ubuntu 18.04 hits the shelves?
2. For the Gnome flashback session, would there be additions to or improvements made on the existing panel applets (would be nice if team created for the task). More specifically, PLEASE bring back the original "Sticky Notes" by Loban A Rahman.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. GNOME Flashback is GNOME + metacity, gnome-flashback, gnome-panel and gnome-applets. So most likely it will be available in 18.04. :)
2. Open upstream bugs with improvements you want to see. GNOME Flashback is not developed / improved by Ubuntu developers - that is not going to change...

Open bugs here:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/page.cgi?id=browse.html&product=gnome-flashback
*(I will move bug to correct package if needed)*